# Script that boycotts Condor in my machine, not having root priviledges

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, distributed-computing

I work in a research institution. The system is maintained by the computer guys, who do an excellent job. All computers are connected and you can access your home from every terminal. The system uses Condor for distributed computing.

Condor is supposed to go unnoticed by the user who sits at the computer at that moment. It only uses CPUs that are idle. This works perfectly almost always. However, recently some users have launch a code in Condor that constantly reads/writes huge files to disk or something, and this freezes the computer I am working in for small amounts of time (like ten seconds or so) very frequently. This is extremely annoying. I don't mind it while I am away of the office, but while I am at the computer I simply don't want it, and the computer guys say there's nothing they can do.

Demanding load from all the 4 CPUs in my machine tells condor to stop. So I launch 4 or more very demanding processes in my terminal, and wait a bit until I see that there are no condor processes running, with the linux command 'top'. Then I am free to work uninterrupted for a while. Until Condor starts again...

Is there some kind of script I can do to boycott Condor in a better and unattended way? I am thinking of demanding a huge load from all CPUs for a fraction of a second every so many minutes, for instance.

Comment: I can understand this seems a horrible behavior, but I am really fed up of being interrupted at work and I need to stop Condor, just during my working hours.

Answer (score 1):

Things would probably work better if you worked with your computer guys instead of against them, but here's the basic idea:

You can make a bash script that loops and checks every 5 seconds or so for the condor processes. If it finds it, you can fire up your overload processes, until it is gone. Then you can resume the loop.

Something along these lines:

```
while true; do
  if ***ps command that checks for condor process***; then
      ***command that launches overload processes***
      while ***condor process is still running***; do
          sleep 1
      done
      ***kill overload processes***
  fi
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I need. But it is pseudocode. Could you be a bit more explicit? - Also, it would be great to know how to stop executing this script once I log out, so that Condor can use my machine while I am not at my desktop (see? I am not such a ass)